# Constraint validated with lower level than level set. ex : INFO (from BLOCKER) in jqassitant

Tags: jqassistant

When running the jqassistant plugin I can see the following lines in the logs

```
[INFO] Validating constraint 'XXXXX' with severity: 'INFO (from BLOCKER)'
```

I have set the concepts and the constraint with severity blocker so I do not understand this log.

I am using 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the message INFO (from BLOCKER) indicates that your rule has a default severity of BLOCKER but has been included in a group with INFO, e.g.

```
<includesConstraint refId="myrule" severity="info" />
```

Can you verify this?

Cheers,

Dirk

Comment: I do not specify the severity inside the include <includeConstraint refId="XXXXX" />

Is that the reason ?

Comment: By the way where can I find the XSD ? (see github issue #202)

Comment: Would be good to be able to be able to set this property at group level IMO

Comment: If you include the constraint without specifying a severity then you should see blocker. Can you provide snippets of your rule definitions, maybe there's a bug in 1.1.2 with it? The upcoming 1.1.3 allows setting a severity on group level such that all included rules will take its severity.